# Python - convertir de string a lista

Tags: python, lista

Tras leer un archivo excel, quedarme con una columna del dataset y seleccionar los valores únicos, quiero convertirlo a una lista.

El excel original es:

```
Unnamed: 0                                 Pollster  Pollster Rating ID  \
0             1                      Monmouth University                 215   
1             2                             Selzer & Co.                 304   
2             3             ABC News/The Washington Post                   3   
3             4  Siena College/The New York Times Upshot                 448   
4             5        Field Research Corp. (Field Poll)                  94   
..          ...                                      ...                 ...   
448         449                             SurveyMonkey                 324   
449         450                 Nielson Brothers Polling                 231   
450         451                             TCJ Research                 327   
451         452                       Humphrey Institute                 143   
452         453                       Jayhawk Consulting                 157   


 Banned by 538  Unnamed: 8  Predictive    Plus-Minus  ...  \
0              no         NaN                 -1.565887  ...   
1              no         NaN                 -1.326442  ...   
2              no         NaN                 -1.285369  ...   
3              no         NaN                 -1.100981  ...   
4              no         NaN                 -1.093440  ...   
..            ...         ...                       ...  ...   
448            no         NaN                  2.589050  ...   
449            no         NaN                  2.955172  ...   
450           yes         NaN                  2.964047  ...   
451            no         NaN                  3.030633  ...   
452            no         NaN                  3.365468  ...
```

El código es:

```
excel = pd.read_excel(excel_doc, engine='openpyxl')
excel = excel[excel['Banned by 538'] != 'yes']
excel = excel['Pollster'].unique()

Resultado
excel = ['Monmouth University' 'Selzer & Co.' 'ABC News/The Washington Post'
 'Siena College/The New York Times Upshot' 'YouGov']
```

La opción `excel = list(excel)` no es la adecuada porque lo convierte en una lista de un único elemento.

```
['Monmouth UniversitySelzer & Co.ABC News/The Washington PostSiena College/The New York Times UpshotYouGov']
```

Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: podrias poner el archivo de excel?

Comment: @Christian, perdona, soy bastante nuevo con esto y no sé cómo adjuntar el archivo. Estoy buscando cómo hacerlo

Comment: simplemente hazlo igual que en tu pregunta anterior

Comment: Coloca el archivo en algún sitio público. Luego edita tu pregunta para agregar el link correspondiente.

Comment: @Christian, ah ok, pensaba que el propio archivo. Ya lo he añadido

Comment: No entiendo... lo que muestras como resultado `excel_doc` ¿no debería ser `excel`? Creo que `excel_doc` es el nombre del archivo, y no la lista resultante, no?. Por otro lado, cómo es que en esa lista faltan las comas separando las cadenas? Creo que de ahí te viene el problema, que quizás lo has copiado y pegado de algún output, sin añadir esas comas. Ah, y no veo el link a la excel, que dices que has añadido en la pregunta.

Comment: cual es la columna `Banned by 538`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno creo que estas confundiendo algunas variables. `excel_doc` es la ruta o tu archivo para leer, en ningun momento le asignas un nuevo valor, al hacer `excel = excel['Pollster'].unique()` e imprimir la variable `excel` nos da el resultado que dices.
Para solucionar tu problema basta con hacer

```py
...
excel = list(df['Pollster'].unique())
print(excel)
```

Dando como resultado

```py
['Monmouth University', 'Selzer & Co.', 'ABC News/The Washington Post', 'Siena College/The New York Times Upshot', 'Field Research Corp. (Field Poll)']
```

Comment: muchas gracias. Con esta entrada y la otra trato de hacer que funcione, porque el error de la matriz vacía, sigue apareciendo.

Comment: Haz un `print()` de la lista que obtienes y verifica que todo este bien, como te dije a mi me funciona perfecto, en todo caso haz otra pregunta, ya que no se relaciona con lo que preguntas acá